# Why does the following javascript code print the result three times?

Tags: javascript

The "steve" contact is printed three times in the console.

```
var friends = {
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "555555555",
        address: ["One Infinite Loop", "Cupertino", "CA", "98052"]
    },
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "555555555",
        address: ["One Microsoft way", "Redmond", "WA", "98052"]
    }
};

var list = function (friends) {
    for (var firstName in friends) {
        console.log(firstName);
    }
};

var search = function (name) {
    for (var steve in friends) {
        if (friends[steve].firstName === name) {
            console.log (friends[steve]);
            return friends [steve];
        }
    }
};
```

Instructions: Define a function search that takes a single argument, name. If the argument passed to the function matches any of the first names in friends, it should log that friend's contact information to the console and return it.

Comment: This code is not printing anything at all. None of the functions was actually called.

Comment: When I run the search function with "Steve" I see only one value printed. The list function just prints the keys of the object referred to by the friends variable ("steve" and "bill").

Comment: If you do `search('Steve')` in console you will get 2 lines printed. Which is kinda expected :)

Comment: The `search` function works fine, it just both prints *and* returns the object found at `friends[steve]` when calling with argument `'Steve'`. So twice, not 3 times.

Comment: When you do `search('Steve')` you will get 2 result in the console because 1 is the console and other is the return

Answer (score 0):

```
var search = function(name) {
    for(var name in friends) {
        if(friends[name].firstName) {
            console.log(friends[name]);
            return friends[name];
        }
    }
};
```

its a bridge to victory...try it!